# reduce_parallel is not a thread-safe function?

Tags: c++, tbb

I want to call parallel_reduce to sum the vector elements. But I find that if the vector elements is enough, the result is not correct. Please help me how to use this function.

```
// prepare data
    const size_t allNum = 1000000;
    std::vector<double> a;
    for (int i = 0; i < allNum; ++i)
    {
        a.push_back(double(i + 1));
    }

    // λ func
    auto f = [&]() -> double {
        return tbb::parallel_reduce(tbb::blocked_range<size_t>(0, allNum), 
            0.0,
            [&](const tbb::blocked_range<size_t>& r, double init) -> double {
            for (int i = r.begin(); i < r.end(); ++i)
            {
                init += a[i];
            }
            return init;
        },
            [](double f, double s) -> double {
            return f + s;
        }
            /*std::plus<double>()*/);
    };

    // call λ func, get the result
    double correctResult = (1.0 + 1000000.0) * 500000.0;
    double sum = f(); // sum != correctResult
    // sum is different every loop
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? Also, just a hint, think about indentation, it seems pretty arbitrary and inconsistent. For one, it distracts readers here, but it also makes it harder to understand and get right, even for you. That said, as a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: What are the values you get?

Comment: BTW, using a `&` default capture for lambdas is typically a bad idea when the lambda is executed in multiple threads and those captured resources are accessed without any synchronization. Also, if you use it, you don't think about what you want to capture and why, which is a bad idea in and of itself.

Comment: In the example of `tbb::parallel_reduce` the block range is accepted by value. In your case you accept it by const reference. This could be the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much,  the result of the code above is correct. The code posted here was modified and the incorrect result caused by my previous code. @UlrichEckhardt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried running the above code. It was working fine and got the correct results too!

For more information about parallel_reduce, refer to the below links:
https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/tbb-documentation/top/intel-threading-building-blocks-developer-reference/algorithms/parallelreduce-template-function.html

https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-1-4842-4398-5.pdf

Thanks,
Santosh